# git gui is not working after software update to macOS Big Sur to 11.4

Tags: git, macos, github, macos-big-sur, git-gui

Whenever I try to execute the 'git gui' command on terminal it shows

```
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui: line 8: /usr/local/git/share/git-gui/lib/Git Gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish: No such file or directory
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui: line 8: exec: /usr/local/git/share/git-gui/lib/Git Gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I'm facing this issue today after a software update of macOS Big Sur.
Current version is 11.4

Comment: You must install the tck/tk package (it is optional).

Comment: I have tried that too

Comment: The path shown here suggests that your particular Git installation expects tcl/tk's `wish` shell to be installed in the `Git Gui.app/` directory itself, which seems ... odd/wrong. My `wish` is in `/usr/bin/wish`.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrade, still didn't found any usable solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is resolved now.

First, when I executed `git --version` it returned with `git version 2.23.0`.

As some solution provided by people, while uninstalling git using `$ brew uninstall git`. Got another problem of `No available formula or cask with the name "git".`

After uninstalling git using `/usr/local/git/uninstall.sh`. The git command
`git --version` returned `git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`.

Now using only Apple-distributed Git.

Conclusion,
Just execute `/usr/local/git/uninstall.sh`

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall git and git-gui.

```
$ brew uninstall git
$ brew install git
$ brew install git-gui
$ brew link git-gui
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case new installation of git with overriding symlinks worked:

```sh
$ brew uninstall git
$ brew install git

# Force the link and overwrite all conflicting files
$ brew link --overwrite git

# List all files that would be deleted
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run git

# Force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
$ brew link --overwrite autoconf

# All files that would be deleted:
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf
```